# ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've just installed tensorflow but when typing :

```
import tensorflow
```

I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 914, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: Une routine d\u2019initialisation d\u2019une bibliothèque de liens dynamiques (DLL) a échoué.    

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:    

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'    

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:    

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 914, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: Une routine d\u2019initialisation d\u2019une bibliothèque de liens dynamiques (DLL) a échoué.    

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:    

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'    


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.    

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems    

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I install tensorflow like this :

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

I use python 3.5.3, with Windows 10 Pro.
I re-install several times tensorflow but I can't solve this issue.
I know that this problem has been solved many times but not with CPU-only tensorflow. That's why I asked you this question.
How can I do that.
Thanks in advance for your response.

EDIT : I found that tensorflow is trying to import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal as a module but in fact it's a *.pyd

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and the problem was with the version of TensorFlow. Follow the below steps in order to remedy this situation:

1. Open the terminal via Anaconda navigator.
2. Run the command:
   `conda install tensorflow`
3. Try importing tensorflow again and it will just work fine.